# WCF on mono: alternatives?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, mono

I have a C# application which needs to do a SOAP call to a 3rd party web service.
I made a simple console application to test and started by adding a service reference using the wdsl.
VS2013 is creating classes and methods and I can send a request and I get a valid response back. Although the webservice is on https I needed to set `<security enableUnsecuredResponse="true" />` in my app config. 
This test is working fine on my Win8 dev machine.

I need to run this piece of code on a Ubuntu server with Mono and sadly Mono hasn't implemented all WCF stuff.

I first get complaints about missing method `enableUnsecuredResponse`, when I remove it I get a `System.NullReferenceException`.

So this road is leading nowhere. 
What is a good alternative for WCF which will work in Mono as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of links, which describe usage of soap services in mono.
But you will have to do that in "mono-first" way. I mean, develop your client with mono and mono tools.

1. http://www.mono-project.com/archived/web_services/#consuming-web-services
2. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/Application_Fundamentals/Web_Services/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mimas for your reply.

We managed to solve it by using `var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();` and create the request our-self using `XmlWriter` and handle the response our-self as well.
It is a lot more work but at least it is working in MONO as well.